# creating google storage bigquery table with partitiontime

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a table in BigQuery that is partitioned by ingestion time (`_PARTITIONTIME`), and I want to move the table to be stored in google storage but have the same structure and partitioned by `_PARTITIONTIME`, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I can proposed you a script that do that in one shot. maybe not optimized, but I tested and it works

```
DECLARE number_of_entry INT64;
DECLARE i INT64 default 0;
DECLARE current_entry INT64;

SET (number_of_entry) = (
Select count(*) 
from `<projectID>.<dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
where table_name='<Your partitioned table>'
);

LOOP
  set i = i + 1;
  if i > number_of_entry then
    leave;
   end if;
# Get the value of the current entry based on the rowid()
   set current_entry = (
select entry 
FROM (
  select entry,row_number() over() as row 
  from (
    select partition_id as entry 
    from `<projectID>.<dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`
    where table_name='<Your partitioned table>
  ) 
  where row = i
);
   EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
    uri='gs://<YourBucket>/export-splited/' || current_entry || '-*.csv',
    format='CSV',
    overwrite=true,
    header=true,
    field_delimiter=',') AS
  select ...... 
  from `<projectID>.<dataset>.<Your partitioned table>` 
  where _PARTITIONTIME=PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d",current_entry);
END LOOP;
```